# Get Mac Adress on a Multitech (cellular router)

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, mac-address

I'm working on bash script to get some information about an external network. I want to get mac address of a Raspberry connected to my cellular router but I can't access to raspberry due to company restriction.

Furthermore, the router are based on a restricted linux, so it's impossible to install software thanks to apt or other alternative. arp or arp-scan don't exist. I find this command line to have the mac address :

```sh
cat /proc/net/arp
```

I have this output :

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.2.200    0x1         0x0         b4:***********:b7     *        br0
192.168.2.110    0x1         0x2         b8:***********:e8     *        br0
```

I just need to have the first HW address but after many tests like cut, grep... I didn't find any solution to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you want always MAC from second row or from line starting with 192.168.2.200?

Comment: Only the first line. I am trying this echo $(cat file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f23) where there is the ouptut in file.txt. But I have this : address b4:9c:df:f0:88:b1 b8:27:eb:2f:ac:ec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From second row print fourth column:

```
awk 'NR==2{print $4}' /proc/net/arp
```

Output:

```
b4:***********:b7
```